# differentiating an expression in differential form

Tags: derivatives, physics, differential-forms

I haven't been familiar with what looks like differential forms so hoping to get some help here.

The extensive total enthalpy of a system is $H$.
The intensive specific enthalpy of this system is $h=\frac{H}{m}$ where m is the mass of the substance.

So, $H = U + PV$ so its corresponding intensive specific enthalpy is $h = u + pv$ after dividing $H, U, PV$ by $m$ with $H$ the enthalpy, $U$ the internal energy of the system, $P$ the pressure and $V$ the volume.

In a text I am reading, the author worked:

$dh = du + Pdv + vdP$ which appears to be in differential form.

To be clearer:

*dV(or dP)* - what is $V( or P)$ being differentiated with respect to?

I fail to follow this. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I realise what was wrong - provided an answer below

Comment: What do you not understand?  $h=u+Pv$ where $u=U/m$ and $v=V/m$.

Comment: I've edited the question to make clearer what I'm asking.

Comment: [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(mathematics)) is an article on differentials.

Comment: Differentials do not require independent variable necessarily, but you can consider $t$ (time) as independent variable here.

Comment: I don't know much about thermodynamics but from a differential geometry perspective, it seems like you have a state function $h$ on your state space with local coordinates or "state variables" $u, v, P$; so e.g. $dh = \frac{\partial h}{\partial u} du + \frac{\partial h}{\partial v} dv + \frac{\partial h}{\partial P} dP$.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't with the mathematics but with the physical implications following from the expression I am working with.

For the benefit of future audiences:

Note that (some included for completion):

$(S, V) \rightarrow U = Q - pdV: internal \space energy$

$(S, p) \rightarrow H = U + pV: enthalpy$

$(T, V) \rightarrow F = U - TS: helmholtz \space free \space energy$

$(T, p) \rightarrow G = U + pV - TS: gibbs \space free \space energy$

Invoking total differentiability on $U = U(S, V):$

$dU = \frac{\partial U}{dS}|_{v}dS + \frac{\partial U}{dV}|_{S}dV$

But $U = Q + pV = TS + pV$

$ \rightarrow \frac{\partial U}{dS}|_{v} = T$

$ \rightarrow \frac{\partial U}{dV}|_{S} = p$

By substitution, this yields:

$dU = TdS + pdV$ as is claimed by the author.

Answer (score 0):

I think it follows from the fact that $pv = \frac{PV}{m}$ so if you consider the differential of that, you get, using the product rule that

$
d(pv) = d(\frac{PV}{m}) = dP \cdot \frac{V}{m} + \frac{P}{m}dV = vdP+pdV
$

Comment: I follow this but what is $dV$ differentiating $V$ with respect to?

Comment: Normally the differential is something physicists use to refer to a quantity changing slightly, in this case probably with respect to time.

Comment: @Pablo [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(mathematics)) is an article on differentials.

Comment: You don't actually have to differentiate with respect to something.  Take all your derivative rules, multiply them by $dx$, and you will have differential rules.  Example: $d(x^2 + 3x) = 2x\,dx + 3\,dx$.  This works with multiple variables as well: $d(x^2 + xy + z^3) = 2x\,dx + x\,dy + y\,dx + 3z^2\,dz$.

Comment: @Pablo I have provided an answer - hope this helps you too